# Add Days Google Script

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I wondered if anyone could help. I have a script where I am pulling out data from a spreadsheet list, where this is a match for this week (basically an events list, to produce a weekly agenda). I will use a for loop to increment the days to add on, but I am just trying to make it work for one day for now...

The first column is the data in format dd/mm/yyy

I am trying to take today's increment by 1 and then search through the list to find a match. The searching etc, I can make work, but the date part is just not playing. I wondered if anyone could advise.

E.g. Date Column A:
06/07/2021
06/07/2021
01/11/2021
01/11/2021
01/11/2021
01/11/2021
02/09/2021
02/09/2021

```
 var selectedDate = row[0];
   
selectedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(selectedDate), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");

 var currdate = new Date();
  currdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(selectedDate), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var daystochange = 1;
  var newdate = new Date(currdate.getFullYear, currdate.getMonth, currdate.getDay+daystochange );
```

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Only use `Utilities.formatDate()` to output dates, not to work with dates.

The JavaScript date object has all you need to work with dates and compare. When you use the `Utilities` function it converts it to a string, and so you lose all the functionality of the Date object.

Also bear in mind that if you have dates, that are formatted as dates in your sheet, they will automatically be returned as Date objects.

For example, if your sheet has a date in cell `A1`

```js
var date = Sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
date instanceof Date // true
```

Once you have your date, if you want to add one day to it, you can take an approach similar to what you have already done:

```js
var selectedDate = new Date(2021, 1, 15)
var newdate = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), selectedDate.getDate() + 1);
console.log(newdate) // Tue Feb 02 2021 00:00:00
```

Note - use `getDate` to return the day of the month, `getDay` only returns day of the week.

To check if two dates are the same, you can write a function to compare:

```js
function isSameDate(a, b) {
    return  a instanceof Date &&
        b instanceof Date &&
        a.getYear() === b.getYear() &&
        a.getMonth() === b.getMonth() &&
        a.getDate() === b.getDate() 
}
```

This function will return `true` if the dates are the same.

#### Reference

- [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I also had an issue where the spreadsheet date column was formatted as text; which was also causing my comparison to fail! This really helps massively, and now does exactly what I need. Thank you.